# How to reference a tuple as part of an attribute for a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I want to reference an element of a tuple as an attribute to a data frame:

There df is a dataframe with Square Feet as an attribute:

```
tup1 = [(Square_Feet, 5000)];
```

This is the area where I want to reference the first element of the tuple
desired outcome:

```
df.Square_Feet
```

How do I do this referencing: `tup1[0]`?

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij why'd you add the MATLAB tag here? This is not MATLAB for certain (square brackets are not used for indexing). Judging your profile, I suggest you do not add tags of languages you do not speak. Instead, leave a comment for the OP to add the relevant language tag.

Comment: Leigh, from your questions thus far on SO I see you have been only asking about Python. Please do note that there are a myriad of programming languages one can ask about here, not only Python. In the future, please do add the Python tag yourself. This to help visibility of your question, since most people filter on language, not on secondary types such as dataframes (which happen to be big in R as well)

Answer (score 0):

Tup1 above is in the format of a list. If you have a list of tuples like below:

```
tups = [('Square_Feet', 5000), ('Square_Feet', 3000), ('Square_Feet', 4000)]
```

The you can easily convert those tuples into a Series of the Data Frame as shown below:

```
df['Square_Feet'] = pd.Series(tup[1] for tup in thelist)
```

The output would look like this:

```
>>> df['Square_Feet']
0    5000
1    3000
2    4000
```